# In python2.7, why urllib2 cant read the whole page

Tags: python, urllib2

I tried to get followers' names of a user.

[image: program]

And I found the program only read the first 12 users in the grid, and completely ignore the rest:

[image: users grid]

Comment: Is all the HTML visible onload? Or is some of it dynamically attached to the DOM by user input?

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You'll never be able to scrape sites like Pinterest, Facebook, Twitter or Google with three lines of code (and you'll be banned as soon as you get there). Instead, take a look at its [API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/?).

Answer (score 0):

I checked that link, the followers only load as you scroll down the page... You'll need to use something other than urllib to scrape all the data. Maybe try this: https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser